# Vuex getter returns undefined value

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm trying to write a getter for my state the problem is that it returns an undefined value but I'm 100% sure that in articleEan is an object that has an Are_EanNr value of 1234567.

This is the getter I'm writing is supposed to return the first object in the articleEan Array that has the same EanNr as the parameter.

```
const getters = {
  findArByEan: state => {
    return (eancode) => {                   // logging eancode results in 1234567
      state.articleEan.find(item => { 
        return item.Are_EanNr === eancode
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Where's my mistake?

After Changing it to:

```
findArByEan: (state) => (eancode) => state.articleEan.find(item => item.Are_EanNr === eancode),
```

Problem still occurs. This is how I'm calling the getter from a component:

```
const getters = {
      ...useGetters('vm', [
        'orderRow',
        'customer',
        'article',
        'additionalData',
        'findArByEan',
      ]),
      ...useGetters('user', ['user']),
    };

const Ar = getters.findArByEan.value(eancode.value);  // Ar = undefined
```

Edit:
When looping over the state I'm getting just the indices of the object in array.

```
log('ArtEan:', artEan.value); // correct output => Array with 38 objects
      for(const item in artEan.value) {
        log(item); // Logs just the index of array
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second arrow function does not return anything so it's `undefined`

```js
const getters = {
  findArByEan: state => {
    return (eancode) => {                   // logging eancode results in 1234567
      return state.articleEan.find(item => { 
        return item.Are_EanNr === eancode
      })
    }
  }
}
```

You can also do it this way without any return.

```js
const getters = {
  findArByEan: (state) => (eancode) => state.articleEan.find(item => item.Are_EanNr === eancode)
}
```

---

I would recommand reading the [arrow function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

For example, those 2 functions works the same but one is tidier ;)

```js
const numberSquare1 = (number) => {
  return number * number
}

const numberSquare2 = (number) => number * number

console.log(numberSquare1(2))
console.log(numberSquare2(2))
```

Comment: Error still occurs after changing the way you suggested.
This is how I'm calling the getter:

`const Ar = getters.findArByEan.value(eancode.value);` 
`log('Ar', Ar); // returns undefined`

Comment: I guess you should call it with `getters.findArByEan(eancode.value);`

Comment: Error: `TypeError: getters.findArByEan is not a function`

Comment: Then i guess you error come from the fact that `state.articleEan.find(item => item.Are_EanNr === eancode)` returns `undefined`. Try to console.log your state and check if your value exists.